# How to change inner html of an <img> tag?

Tags: jquery, html, image, attr

This is being output:

```
<img width="1080" height="1080" src="/image.jpg" class="post-image" alt="image" />
```

I need to change it to this: (`src` → `data`)

```
<img width="1080" height="1080" data="/image.jpg" class="post-image" alt="image" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the simple JQ below :

first get the `src` then add it as `data` , then remove the `src`

```js
var src = $("img").attr("src")
$("img").attr("data", src).removeAttr("src")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img width="1080" height="1080" src="/image.jpg" class="post-image" alt="image" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attr` and `removeAttr` of jQuery, to `get`, `set` and `remove` attributes.

```js
var img = $("img");
img.attr("data", img.attr("src")).removeAttr("src");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img width="1080" height="1080" src="/image.jpg" class="post-image" alt="image" />
```